# Como quitar ceros de una cadena alfanumerica en java

Tags: java

Como puedo sacar ceros de una cadena que es alfanumerica, y que no siempre cumple un mismo patron ejemplo: 000265552L 00002655L, yo necesitaria solo extraer 265552L

Comment: puedes usar `replaceAll()`..`cadenaAlfanumerica.replaceAll("0", "");` reemplazas los 0 por espacio cerrado

Answer (score 1):

String cadena = "000265552L";

```
    String nueva = "";

    nueva = cadena.replaceAll("0", "");

    System.out.println(nueva);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).